# Query jpql with max

Tags: java, jpql, java-ee-6, java-ee-7, java-ee-8

I have an entity "Song" and i need a query to get the song(not the title, the entity) with the max number of votes (there are three types of votes called votes1, votes2, votes3).
It's possible to define this type of query in jpql?

I tried with this type of code but is syntactically wrong.

@NamedQuery(name = FIND_FOR_MAX_VOTES, query = "SELECT  s FROM Song s WHERE (SELECT (MAX s.votes1+ s.votes2+ s.votes3))"),

Comment: Instead of WHERE, try "ORDER BY max(...) DESCENDING LIMIT 1". Also is `s` really a column name? The first SELECT should specify a column name or "*".

Comment: Yes s is a column and i have other queries with select s that correctly work.

Comment: Can you write the full query? I tried  @NamedQuery(name = FIND_FOR_MAX_VOTES, query = "SELECT s FROM Song s ORDER BY max(s.votes1+ s.votes2+ s.votes3) DESCENDING LIMIT 1") but i got many warnings like "the order by item is not a valid exception, the left/right side of the addition is not a valid arithmetic expression, DESCENDIN and LIMIT are not defined in FROM clause

Comment: "the left/right side of the addition is not a valid arithmetic expression" means that s.votes1 etc are not data types that can be added, such as integers.

Comment: That's weird because votes1 etc... are integers.

Comment: Sorry, I got it a bit wrong: "max" doesn't make sense there. It should be "SELECT s FROM Song s ORDER BY s.votes1 + s.votes2 + s.votes3 DESC". (I think "LIMIT 1" is not recognised, but you can just get the first row that comes back and ignore the rest.) Try it now.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, try "SELECT s FROM Song s WHERE s.votes1 + s.votes2 + s.votes3 = (SELECT max(s.votes1 + s.votes2 + s.votes3) FROM Song)"